# Trying to figure out how to move jquery ui buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I read a number of of jquery ui button related questions on here, and the one thing I don't see anyone asking which might point out that my approach is wrong - but I need to be able to do one of two things:

1. either add buttons to a jquery UI dialog like normal and reposition them where I need them on the dialog (some outside the button pane)
2. or add a button to the view I am rendering inside the dialog and some how get it to inherit the css and behavior of the buttons rendered by jquery.

EDIT:  so to answer some of the questions with specifics.

There is a save and cancel button  currently on the button pane of the dialog.  They should be there.  But I want to add a couple buttons that I am binding with Knockout JS and want to put them in the view that I am loading inside the dialog.

Example:  I have a text box that has a "Add" button that will allow adding the text in the textbox to a listbox (like a combo box).  This is just one of the 2 kinds of additional buttons that work strictly on the dialog's view model.
Any thoughts?

Comment: you already know how to create the button? you just don't know how to position it?

Comment: with respect to item #1, where would you place the buttons?  are you talking about a scenario where the dialog close "x" would be outside of the modal box? i think your responses will depend on what where you plan to put the buttons.

Comment: @scott - correct, I want to put it somewhere outside the button pane.

Comment: here's one way to move buttons outside the button pane: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/VJTSw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found that I Can use jQuery's .content() and .append() methods to allow me to move dom elements and not break the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

once you have created the button just use  .addClass( className ) to the newly created button where the positioning is in the Css Class.